# wcf with basic authentication through reverse proxy

Tags: wcf, authentication, ssl, basic-authentication, reverse-proxy

I have a Web Service which uses basic authentication with ssl through a reverse proxy. It has already cost me quite some time to figure out how to get this working and I still fail to get it fully working.

if you type in the url in the browser https://domain.com/service.svc, it asks for credentials and if correct, you get the overview page of the service.
So that seems to be okay.

But when I try to add the Service to Visual Studio 2010, I get the following error:

> Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 
>   The document format is not recognized (the content type is 'text/html; charset=utf-8').
>   Metadata contains a reference that cannot be resolved: 'https://domain.com/service.svc'.
>   The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Basic realm=NTLM'.
>   The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
>   If the service is defined in the current solution, try building the solution and adding the service reference again.

Here is my web.config

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="MyBinding">
                <!--<httpsTransport authenticationScheme="Basic"/>-->
                <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="Basic" realm="" />                      
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>

    <services>
        <service name="WcfService1.PortalService" behaviorConfiguration="NorthwindBehavior">
            <host>
                <baseAddresses>
                    <add baseAddress="https://domain.com/" />
                </baseAddresses>
            </host>             
            <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding" contract="WcfService1.IPortalService">
                <!--<identity>
                    <servicePrincipalName value=""/>
                </identity>-->
            </endpoint>
            <!--<endpoint address="mex" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="MyBinding" name="mex" contract="WcfService1.IPortalService"></endpoint>-->
        </service>
    </services>

    <serviceHostingEnvironment>
        <baseAddressPrefixFilters>
            <add prefix="https://domain.com/"/>
        </baseAddressPrefixFilters>

    </serviceHostingEnvironment>

    <!--<extensions>
        <bindingElementExtensions>
            <add name="httpsViaProxyTransport" type="WcfService1.HttpsViaProxyTransportElement, WcfService1"/>
        </bindingElementExtensions>
    </extensions>
      <bindings>
        <customBinding>
            <binding name="UserNamePasswordSecured">
                <textMessageEncoding />
                <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport" />
                <httpsViaProxyTransport />
            </binding>
        </customBinding>
    </bindings>-->      

    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="NorthwindBehavior">
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="false" />
                <serviceAuthorization principalPermissionMode="UseAspNetRoles"/>
                <serviceCredentials> <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="MembershipProvider"/></serviceCredentials>

            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="SampleEndpointBehavior">
                <!--<wsdlExtensions location="http://domain.com/PortalService.svc" singleFile="true"/> -->
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

</system.serviceModel>
```

I tried numerous things like following this post: http://blog.hackedbrain.com/2006/09/26/how-to-ssl-passthrough-with-wcf-or-transportwithmessagecredential-over-plain-http/ but not very succesful.

I also tried to add site bindings to http because the wsdl is generating the server name instead of the domain name, so maybe there is something wrong at that end as well...

So hopefully someone can provide me with some pointers!

Note that the web.config file has some 'junk' in it because of trying with million different settings...